# Difference between invokeLater/invokeAndWait and asyncExec/syncExec

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a project using Eclipse RCP and Swing. I see two pairs of methods `invokeLater()/invokeAndWait()` and `asyncExec()/syncExec()` being used a lot.

From what I understand, `invokeLater()/invokeAndWait()` belong to Swing, and `asyncExec()/syncExec()` belong to Eclipse. But what is the difference between these two pairs of methods?

If they are all used to execute a task on the UI thread, is it the same UI thread that they post the task onto? Are `invokeLater()` and `asyncExec()` interchangeable?

Is there any potential pitfall (e.g. deadlock, etc.) if I'm calling e.g. `syncExec()` from `invokeAndWait()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse uses the SWT User Interface, this is a completely separate UI system from Swing. `asyncExec()/syncExec()` are part of the SWT system.

If you are writing an Eclipse RCP or plug-ins for Eclipse you should be writing SWT code.

SWT does provide a method of using Swing code but this should be a last resort.

Since they are totally different UI systems each with its own event loop `invokeAndWait` and `syncExec` are not interchangeable. It is very easy to get into a mess when there are two UI event loops running.